# Issue in a code to register first 100 key pressed and length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

Need you help, it works only for the first one...
The idea is to register first 100 keypresses with the time and the length they are pressed.

```
from pynput import keyboard 
import time, os

tinit = time.time()
Resultatfichier=open('Keyregister','a')
x = 1

def callb(key): #what to do on key-release
    ti1 = str(time.time() - t)[0:8] #converting float to str, slicing the float
    ti2 = str(time.time() - tinit)[0:8] #converting float to str, slicing the float
    Resultatfichier.write("At "+ti2+" The key " + str(key) + " is pressed for "+ ti1 + " seconds\n") 
    x = x + 1
    return False #stop detecting more key-releases
def callb1(key): #what to do on key-press
    return False #stop detecting more key-presses

while x <= 100:  
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press = callb1) as listener1: #setting code for listening key-press
        listener1.join()

        t = time.time() #reading time in sec

    with keyboard.Listener(on_release = callb) as listener: #setting code for listening key-release
        listener.join()

Resultatfichier.close()
```

Comment: how the length should work?

Comment: ti1 is the length (time between key press and key release) / ti2 is the time between the beginning of the program and the key press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, it seems to work fine if you declare `global x` in your callb function:

```py
from pynput import keyboard 
import time, os

tinit = time.time()
Resultatfichier=open('Keyregister','a')
x = 1

def callb(key): #what to do on key-release
    global x # if not then 'x' is assigned before creation because of scope of variable
    ti1 = str(time.time() - t)[0:8] #converting float to str, slicing the float
    ti2 = str(time.time() - tinit)[0:8] #converting float to str, slicing the float
    Resultatfichier.write("At "+ti2+" The key " + str(key) + " is pressed for "+ ti1 + " seconds\n") 
    x = x + 1
    return False #stop detecting more key-releases
def callb1(key): #what to do on key-press
    return False #stop detecting more key-presses

while x <= 10:  
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press = callb1) as listener1: #setting code for listening key-press
        listener1.join()

        t = time.time() #reading time in sec

    with keyboard.Listener(on_release = callb) as listener: #setting code for listening key-release
        listener.join()

Resultatfichier.close()
```